# jQuery textbox change event doesn't fire, mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to fire a method in JQuery, but it won't work.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrUpdateMethod", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
     //some code
     <div class="row">

            <div class="period-list">
                <span class="advance-season">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign margin-right10"></span>Something
                </span>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Periods.Count; i++)
                {
                    <div class="form-group period">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Periods[i].Id, new { @Value = Model.Periods[i].Id })                            
                        <div class="pull-left inline-block col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">                                
                            <div class="text-box-with-icon calendar margin-bottom10">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Periods[i].From, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control period-from", @onchange = "periodChange();" })                                    
                                <span class="icon"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left inline-block col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">                              
                            <div class="text-box-with-icon calendar margin-bottom10">                                   
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Periods[i].To, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control period-to" })
                                <span class="icon"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                 }
                 //some code
            </div>
       </div>

}
```

And my jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function periodChanged() {
    $('.period-from .period-to').change(function () {
        alert("click");
        //some code
   });
}
```

As you can see I tried already adding @change to textBox control. Nothing is happening. Maybe I should mention as well, that i I am using validation on model.Periods.From and model.Periods.To. Moreover this view is a partial view.

EDIT:
I changed into:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.period-from .period-to').click(function () {
        alert("click");
        if (Model.Periods.All(p=>p.To.Day - p.From.Day + 1 <= 7)) {

        }
    });
});
```

but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Just remove the enclosing `function periodChanged() {` (and make sure you script is at the bottom of the page or wrapped in `$(document).ready()`

Comment: You're assigning an event handler within an event handler so the inner one will only fire on the second event onwards. You should remove one of them. Also note that `change` only fires when the value of the `input` is changed, not on 'click' as your `alert` suggests

Comment: Even if this is a partial view?

Comment: Scripts should never be in partial views (move it to the main view or its layout)

Comment: Do I really have to? Because i wanted to do some changes to my Model that this view contains.

Comment: I tried moving it to my main view but it still doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrUpdateMethod", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
     //some code
     <div class="row">

            <div class="period-list">
                <span class="advance-season">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign margin-right10"></span>Something
                </span>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Periods.Count; i++)
                {
                    <div class="form-group period">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Periods[i].Id, new { @Value = Model.Periods[i].Id })                            
                        <div class="pull-left inline-block col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">                                
                            <div class="text-box-with-icon calendar margin-bottom10">
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Periods[i].From, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control period-from", @onchange = "periodChange();" })                                    
                                <span class="icon"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pull-left inline-block col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">                              
                            <div class="text-box-with-icon calendar margin-bottom10">                                   
                                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Periods[i].To, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control period-to" })
                                <span class="icon"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                 }
                 //some code
            </div>
       </div>

}

@*call the jquery.js file in the main or here*@

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document.ready(function(){

    $('.period-from .period-to').change(function () {
        alert("click");
        //some code
   });

});
</script>
```

this will fire the alert , but this is not enough for your case, you have to do more than this, as the list is generated in loop

your partial view should look like this, attaching the event after the C# code

Comment: Should i use $(document.ready(function(){ even if this is a partial view?

Comment: @kuleczka Jquery will work on partial view also, just write like you would on a normal page

Comment: @kuleczka , the events should be attached after the partial view is loaded, the dynamically generated elements wont have the events, write the event listener in the partial, at the end  , or you can use other methods

Comment: @kuleczka attaching a event multiple times may lead to some unwanted behavior, you can destroy the attached events and then reattach it after the partial views are loaded

Comment: I tried as you can see in edited post, but it still doesn't work. Am I forgetting about sth? Can it not work because of some classes I added to my control or because of validation?

Comment: @kuleczka if you have doubt, create a simple html file and test your code and if fine, forward (hand code or copy the data generated)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
 $(document).on('change','.period-from .period-to') {
    alert("click");
    //some code
 });
```